# How to allow positional argument and aggregate argument to coexist in python argparse?

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I have one positional argument `bar` and another argument `foo` that parses to a list:

```
import argparse
p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('-foo', nargs='+')
p.add_argument('bar')
```

If `bar` proceeds `foo`, everything works fine

```
print(p.parse_args('b -foo f1 f2 f3'.split()))
```

This gives rise to `Namespace(bar='b', foo=['f1', 'f2', 'f3'])`.

However, if `bar` is after `foo`, it complains that `bar` is not provided, i.e.,

```
print(p.parse_args('-foo f1 f2 f3 b'.split()))
```

gives rise to

> usage: **main**.py [-h] [-foo FOO [FOO ...]] bar
>   **main**.py: error: the following arguments are required: bar

It is a bit unfortunate that the usage hint actually suggests the wrong ordering.

In reality, I am adding `nargs='+'` to an existing parser to add functionality, and there may be scripts somewhere with the 'wrong' ordering, i.e., `-foo` proceeds `bar`. And I don't want to break/fix them.

One possible way is to use instead

```
p.add_argument('-foo', action='append')
```

Then the command needs to be triggered by

```
print(p.parse_args('-foo f1 -foo f2 -foo f3 b'.split()))
```

It solves the problem, but it's a bit verbose. Is this the best one can do?

Comment: Does `bar` really have to be positional?  Why not make it '--bar'?

Comment: It is an existing script I am extending and there are other scripts using it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't an easy fix that I know of.  If you want I could find a bug/issue that discusses the issue.

First, regarding usage - the usage code separates optionals and positionals, and displays the positionals last, roughly corresponding to normal POSIX practices.  You could, of course, write your own usage line.

As for the parsing, it alternates parsing positionals and optionals.  When handling positionals it allocates strings (up to the next flag string) according to the `nargs` (several positionals may be handled at once).  And when handling an optional, it allocates values according to its `nargs`.

So in your case `--foo` with `+` gets everything up to the next flag (or '--'), without reserving anything for the positional that might follow.

Reserving one string for `bar` would require some sort of look ahead. That's not a trivial thing to add to the existing code.